# Dynamically add referenced stylesheet to inline styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

**Scenario**

I have created a page where the client can build their own page, calendars, widgets, articles etc. I have created a second Dynamic builder page where they can build their own newsletters.

**Problem**

All my css is referenced with classes, because mailers are very limited I have to add all styles **inline**.

**Question**

Is there a script I can run to grab all referenced styles via class, and add it to the relevant elements/tags inline-styles?

**Example [simple]**

```
<p class='txtBlack'>Hello World</p>
```

Converts to

```
<p class='txtBlack' style='color:#000;'>Hello World</p>
```

*Hope this is clear enough to understand.*

Comment: Mail applications especially Outlook are very limited. I guess your mail results won't look like your web page.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, like I said. But to have everything inline styled, and converted tables...it will have a very close comparison. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `element.currentStyle` and `window.getComputedStyle()` for each element, then 'manually' read what I want and overwrite what I'm sure that doesn't work in mail apps.

I made example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vmc7L/

Another way, is to read rules form style sheets and then apply them to inline style. But what if u got selectors like `.myClass:firstChild>.anotherClass`? :D Maybe jquery can help.

There're methods you need: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks great and works in IE. How can I implement this using jQuery selectors?

Comment: Well, first way is to get every element on page, read its current style, then save it to `style` attribute. Second way is to read every css rule from style sheets, find element that match its selector, then apply css to them. jquery helps alot to find element by selector, I made example: http://jsfiddle.net/w4fUE/

Answer (score 1):

This so answer explains how:
[Can I access the value of invalid/custom CSS properties from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926326/can-i-access-the-value-of-invalid-custom-css-properties-from-javascript)

CSSStyleDeclaration (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration)

```
div {
    width: 100px;
}
```

style:CSSStyleDeclaration object contains cssText:

```
cssText: "width: 100px"
```

CSSStyleDeclaration specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration

To get all elements with class names use:

```
jQuery("[class]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution u can use the "getElementsByClassName" javascript function to collect the elements with the class names specified. But remember this doesnot work IE browsers. So for IE u have to have your own function. Hope this helps u.