# How to access Cascading Variables from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have defined a style sheet using [Cascading Variables](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/#the-CSSVariablesMap-interface).

```
:root {
        --media: narrow;
}

@media all and (min-width: 30rem)
{
        :root {
                --media: wide;
        }
}
```

Firefox understands this and shows me the property in the Inspector.

But how to read it from JavaScript?

I tried it with jQuery 2.1.3 but it does not seem to work:

```
$('html').css('--media')
undefined
$('html').css('media')
undefined
$(':root').css('media')
undefined
```

Which native function I have to use?

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(element, ':root').getPropertyValue('--media');` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS & Javascript: Get a list of CSS custom attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251804/css-javascript-get-a-list-of-css-custom-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064037/rakesh-kumar)!

I got it:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':root')
      .getPropertyValue('--media')
      .trim()
```