# Custom attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get the value of custom attributes. For exemple, for this:

```
<div style="-my-data:3;" id="foo" ></div>
```

I would like to write something like that:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.myData;
```

But it's not working. How can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I access the value of invalid/custom CSS properties from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926326/can-i-access-the-value-of-invalid-custom-css-properties-from-javascript)

Comment: Use jQuery? Though in all seriousness it has a `data()` method...

Comment: Do I still just write `<div style="-my-data:3;" id="foo" ></div>`?

Comment: @user1365010 I'm not sure **every** browser will replace "myData" with "-my-data". You better use document.getElementById("foo").style["-my-data"]

Comment: it doesn't work too : http://jsfiddle.net/Afu8b/

Comment: @user1365010 the "style" property is associated with the inline style attribute, it's empty for CSS rules. Moreover the current behavior is...undefined if the CSS rule is unknown by the browser (so you may get "undefined" or empty string)

Comment: Side question: why do you want to put some custom data inside the CSS? Can't you use custom attributes as posted in answers? Is there a special reason?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [HTML5's custom `data-*` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) instead:

```
<div data-myDataName="3" id="foo"></div>
```

---

Then, to get it via JavaScript, just use this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('data-myDataName'); // '3'
```

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c55nf/

---

**P.S.** Even though it's part of HTML5, it'll still work in older browsers. It was just standardized in HTML5.

Comment: Equivalent using jquery: $('#foo').data('myDataName')

Answer (score 2):

use the html data attribute:

```
<div data-style="3" id="foo"></div>
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("foo").getAttribute("data-style");
```

to retrieve the information

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML custom data attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml):

**HTML**:

```
<div data-myval="3" id="foo" ></div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
alert(document.getElementById("foo").getAttribute('data-myval'));​
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xx6K3/1).