# Creating my own Custom widget in GWT and styling it using my own Custom CSS code

Tags: css, gwt

I have created a custom widget,  basically an Image and a text label.
What must I do so that I can now set the position of the text ( top/left/bottom of the image for example ) using nothing only CSS?  I mean what methods would my class need so that the CSS styling can be applied to it?

ie  Can I have a css class like so

```
.ImageAndLabel 
{
     imagePosition: top;
}
```

Heres my gwt class

```
    public class ImageAndLabel extends Composite
    {
        private Label label = new Label();
        private Image img = new Image("/images/pinkBackground.png");
        protected final FlexTable contentTable;

        public ImageAndLabel()
        {
            contentTable = new FlexTable();
            initWidget(contentTable);
            label.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(40, Unit.PX);
            contentTable.setWidget(0,0,img);
            img.setHeight("200px");
            contentTable.setWidget(0,1,label);
            label.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(0, Unit.PX);
            img.getElement().setId("popupImg");
            label.getElement().setId("popupLabel");
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            label.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

I guess what I'm after is can I create my own Custom CSS codes?

Comment: u can use setStyleName(style)

Comment: contentTable.setStyleName()??

Comment: contentTable.setWidget(0, 0, label);
contentTable.setWidget(1,1,img);

Comment: I don't mean how do I associate a style class with this class.  I mean can I have a style attribute declared as follows  {  myOwnAttribute: top; }   Is this possible?  if So how is the value I put in the attribute applied to my widget?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible - implement your own css propertys. But may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926326/can-i-access-the-value-of-invalid-custom-css-properties-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flextable` method for `alignment`.
example :

```
  flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setAlignment(0, 0, 
      HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Comment: Suppose I want to have a CSS rule that has the attribute {  position: imageOnTop;   OR   position: textOnTop; }  what would I have to do to my class so that the above css would make sense or can I not create custon CSS tags?

Comment: MayoMan ,
ImageAndLabel is in flextable ,
 wherever you add your ImageAndLabel it is added inside flextable so you have to apply css to the widget where you are going to add your ImageAndLabel
ex: horizontalPanel.add(new ImageandLabel) than apply css to horizomtalPanel